# How do I make my simple popup web responsive?

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, mobile-safari

Im new to coding and I am trying to create a simple popup, I want to be able to make this compatible for a mobile website, but I have tried doing a bunch of examples from W3 Schools to make it mobile friendly. I've had no luck in what I tried so I didn't include anything I tried in the code I posted here.  Would someone be able to help me? thank you!

```js
$(function() {
  var overlay = $('<div id="overlay"></div>');
  overlay.show();
  overlay.appendTo(document.body);
  $('.popup').show();
  $('.close').click(function() {
    $('.popup').hide();
    overlay.appendTo(document.body).remove();
    return false;
  });

  $('.x').click(function() {
    $('.popup').hide();
    overlay.appendTo(document.body).remove();
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
#overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  filter: alpha(opacity=70);
  -moz-opacity: 0.7;
  -khtml-opacity: 0.7;
  opacity: 0.7;
  z-index: 100;
  display: none;
}

.cnt223 a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.popup {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 101;
}

.cnt223 {
  min-width: 600px;
  width: 600px;
  min-height: 150px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  background: #f3f3f3;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 103;
  padding: 15px 35px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px #000;
}

.cnt223 p {
  clear: both;
  color: #555555;
  /* text-align: justify; */
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.cnt223 p a {
  color: #d91900;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.cnt223 .x {
  float: right;
  height: 35px;
  left: 22px;
  position: relative;
  top: -25px;
  width: 34px;
}

.cnt223 .x:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='popup'>
  <div class='cnt223'>
    <Center>
      <h1>POPUP!</h1>

      <p>
        <center>
          Body text Lores Ipsum........
          <br>
          <br>
          <b> The next line down</b>
          <br/>
          <br/>
          <a href='' class='close'>Close</a>
      </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks fine in Chrome dev tools using the mobile view. It responds to rotation and adjusts with screen size. What problem are you having?

Answer (score 0):

remove min-width and use max-width:600px instead of width inside .cnt223 class

```
.cnt223 {
 max-width: 600px;
 min-height: 150px;
 margin: 100px auto;
 background: #f3f3f3;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 103;
 padding: 15px 35px;
 border-radius: 5px; 
 box-shadow: 0 2px 5px #000;
}
```

In additonally I reccomend you read about Css media queries to hanlde different screen sizes and more flexible responsive design 
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: Thank you so much I appreciate your help!!